# How to enter commands in invoked subprocess in ssh using invoke_shell?

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, subprocess, paramiko, teraterm

I’m trying to automate ssh connection. In this session i want to send some commands to log on into another subproces.

```
import paramiko
import os
import time 


ip = 'a'
port = 22
username = 'b' 
password = 'c'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip,port,username,password)

channel = ssh.invoke_shell()

out = channel.recv(9999)

channel.send('net-client\n')
channel.send('connect\n')
channel.send('yes\n')
channel.send('password\n')
channel.send('help\n')

while not channel.recv_ready():
    time.sleep(3)

out = channel.recv(9999)
print(out.decode("ascii"))
```

### Manual preparation:

- $(prompt from ssh connection)]
- $ net-client (when i write this command, it open client installed on machine)
- & connect  (I have another prompt because i'm in subprocces, I write 'connect')
- Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes (write 'yes)
  Interactive SSH Authentication
  Type your password:
- Password: 'password' (i write password)
- & (now i'm connected in subproces)

Actual result: 
I have correct answer after "net-client' but when I write next command (in this case 'connect'), this will be written on ssh-connection not i subproces...

I want to continue send commands in this subproces( so put command like connect, password etc.) but my script can't handle this operation.

This my actual print from script:

```
$
net-client
"Correct answer to the command"
& connect
yes
password

help
```

Comment: Why are you using `invoke_shell` instead of `exec_command`?

Comment: According to paramiko documentary `exec_command` open new channel and execute command

Comment: I do not see how that answers my question.

Comment: Hmm, I use invoke_shell to open a interactive shell session on this channel, I don't want to send commands everytime in new ssh session.

Comment: `exec_command` does not open new SSH session. It opens a (virtual) channel within the existing SSH connection.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my answer.

The solution is simple: whitespace '\n' just move to new line. In output I see command that I've send but it was missing "press Enter". Need to change this for '\r' - carriage return, then all of command are 'accepted' by process.